# Sql Server Full Text Search - Getting word occurances/location in text?

Tags: sql-server-2005, indexing, full-text-search

Suppose I have Sql Server (2005/2008) create an index from one of my tables.

I wish to use my own custom search engine (a little more tuned to my needs than Full Text Search).
In order to use it however, I need Sql Server to provide me the word positions and other data required by the search engine.

Is there anyway to query the "index" for this data instead of just getting search results?

Thanks
Roey

Comment: I meant maybe just get as a result a table of "DocumentID, WordID, Occurance" ?

This should not break if MS changes their implementation...

Answer (score 0):

No. And if you could, what happens if Microsoft decide to change their internal data structures? Your code would break.

What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am trying to use my own search engine, not FTS.
But, I cannot implement a fast-enough indexer, SS2008's indexer is much faster, so I want to take advantage of it.

What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldnt rely on SQL servers internal data structures - they are tailored specifically for SQL servers use and aren't acessible for querying anyway.

If you want a fast indexer then you will probably have more success using a pre-written one rather than trying to write your own. Give [Lucene.Net](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/) a try.